# WebRTC Voice Activity Detection

Tags: javascript, audio, webrtc, video-conferencing

I'm implementing a very simple WebRTC audio/video chat room using JavaScript and HTML.

It should run is all major browsers (Chrome, Firefox, Safari and Edge)

The application layout shows all the users currently collaborating, each one inside its own "square".

I would like to **highlight** the user that is currently speaking with a different square border color.

To the best of my knowledge the only way to implement this is using some built-in **VAD API available and exposed to JS** by the browser webrtc stack.

Could you please point me if this is possible, and if so, which API's should I be using ?

Code examples would be very useful.

Answer (score -2):

I've never tried it, but I think you can extract the C++ code from WebRTC related to VAD and build it using WASM.